# Mixing storyboard prototype cells with auto populating data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an auto populating `UITableView` from a `NSMutableArray`. I need to add a static cell to the top of the table from a prototype I built in storyboard.  What is the correct way of doing this?

When I just added the prototype to the storyboard editor, it started out by covering up the first cell.  After reloading the data, it would eventually appear under the other cells.

To make "space" for it, I made the table "editable" with the following code -

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.editing ? wOutputArray.count + 1 : wOutputArray.count;   
}
```

Now it doesn't cover any cells, but it seems as though it doesn't have a home.  At initial view load it's at the top of the table, then after a few refreshes it eventually falls back to the bottom of the table.

**EDIT:**

I'm reading that you can't mix static cells with dynamic cells, and that the table should be split up into sections.

So here I changed-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableViewB{
    return 2;
}
```

&

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewB numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    switch(section){
        case 0:
            return  1;
            break;
        case 1:
            return  wOutputArray.count;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm not sure what to do next...  Is this the right direction?

Comment: Do you only want to display the static cell when the table is being edited or do you want to display it always?

Comment: Always.  The table refreshes with dynamic values; the count stays the same after the view loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, both types of cells that you want to use are prototype cells - they are just different types of cell.

If you just want a static cell at the top of the others then all you need to do is account for it in your table data source methods.

First let the tableview know that there will 1+(dynamic cells count) cells

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return wOutputArray.count + 1    
}
```

Second, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` return the appropriate cell, accounting for the fact that indexPath.row will be 1 more than the element of your array (because row 0 is the static cell)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        cell=tableView.dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier("staticCell",forIndexPath:indexPath)
        //  Any other manipulation as required
    }
    else {
        cell=tableView.dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier("dynamicCell",forIndexPath:indexPath)
        cell.label.text=wOutputArray[indexPath.row-1];  // Or whatever property you want to use
    }

    return cell!
}
```